# Why the size tab in chrome devtools network panel has 2 cells?

Tags: google-chrome, networking, web, google-chrome-devtools, google-docs

[image]
<sub>(source: [twimg.com](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DRyAwpWVwAALX4_.jpg))</sub>

I want to ask that why the size tab has 2 cells? It seems that the over is Encoded Data and the under is Decoded Body, but the developer doc doesn't have explanation about this, and if so, and why some Encoded Data is bigger than Decoded Body(no HTTP2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top number is the transfer size, the bottom number is the actual, decompressed size.

This is covered over in [Text compression with GZIP](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/optimize-encoding-and-transfer#text_compression_with_gzip), but you're right, I need to add it to the DevTools docs. I added a reminder for myself here: https://github.com/google/WebFundamentals/issues/5578

Comment: Thanks for your clarification~ just one question, why sometimes the top load time is longer than bottom even the transfer size is smaller than decompressed size @Kayce Basques

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Decompressed size at maximum should only match the transfer size, never exceed it. File an issue at https://crbug.com if you can consistently reproduce it.